# Why is the result different when the value is greater than a certain number of digits?

Tags: mysql

I'm very sorry, I hurried to send out before trying all the situations, and say sorry to everyone! Following your answers, I tried and overturned what I thought before. As the number of digits changes, I feel very confused. I have not tested how many digits are normal, but I believe this example should be able to tell. Only return the same result as the number of digits to be queried, but there are two situations here. Are the other digits the same? I haven't tried them one by one.

```
  CREATE TABLE `user` (
    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
    `simid` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `name`, `simuid`)
    VALUES
    (1, 'ccc', '6441760021201308940'),
    (3, 'bb', '6441760021201308941'),
    (4, 'bb', '6441760021201308942');
    
    select * from user where simuid = 6441760021201308940;
    result：
    1 ccc 6441760021201308940
    3 bb 6441760021201308941
    4 bb 6441760021201308942
    
    but ：select * from user where simuid = '6441760021201308940';
    result：
    1 ccc 6441760021201308940

    mysql> select * from user;
    +------+------+------------------------+
    | id   | name | simid                  |
    +------+------+------------------------+
    |    5 | ccc  | 6441760021201307159    |
    |    6 | ccc  | 6441760021201307160    |
    |    7 | ccc  | 6441760021201307001    |
    |    8 | ccc  | 6441760021201307000    |
    |    9 | qqq  | 6441760021201308159    |
    |   10 | sss  | 6441760021201308160    |
    |   12 | jjj  | 641760021201308162     |
    |   13 | sss  | 6441760021201308161    |
    |   14 | jjj  | 6417600212013081620    |
    |   15 | sss  | 64417600212013081610   |
    |   21 | zzz  | 6441760021201308970    |
    |   51 | ccc  | 6441760021201308940    |
    |   52 | ddd  | 6441760021201308945    |
    |   53 | bb   | 6441760021201308941    |
    |   54 | bb   | 6441760021201308942    |
    |   55 | eee  | 6441760021201308946    |
    |  100 | sss  | 6441760021201308161000 |
    |  101 | jjj  | 641760021201308162000  |
    |  200 | sss  | 6441760021201308168000 |
    |  201 | jjj  | 6441760021201308169000 |
    | 1000 | aaa  | 64410                  |
    | 1001 | bbb  | 64411                  |
    +------+------+------------------------+
    22 rows in set (0.00 sec)

    select * from user where simid = 6441760021201307159;
        +----+------+---------------------+
        | id | name | simid               |
        +----+------+---------------------+
        |  5 | ccc  | 6441760021201307159 |
        |  6 | ccc  | 6441760021201307160 |
        |  9 | qqq  | 6441760021201308159 |
        | 10 | sss  | 6441760021201308160 |
        +----+------+---------------------+

mysql> select * from user where simid = 6441760021201308160000;
+-----+------+------------------------+
| id  | name | simid                  |
+-----+------+------------------------+
| 100 | sss  | 6441760021201308161000 |
| 200 | sss  | 6441760021201308168000 |
| 201 | jjj  | 6441760021201308169000 |
+-----+------+------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
mysql> select * from user where simid = 6441760021201308160;
+----+------+---------------------+
| id | name | simid               |
+----+------+---------------------+
|  5 | ccc  | 6441760021201307159 |
|  6 | ccc  | 6441760021201307160 |
|  9 | qqq  | 6441760021201308159 |
| 10 | sss  | 6441760021201308160 |
+----+------+---------------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from user where simid = 6441760021201308161;
+----+------+---------------------+
| id | name | simid               |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 13 | sss  | 6441760021201308161 |
| 21 | zzz  | 6441760021201308970 |
| 51 | ccc  | 6441760021201308940 |
| 52 | ddd  | 6441760021201308945 |
| 53 | bb   | 6441760021201308941 |
| 54 | bb   | 6441760021201308942 |
| 55 | eee  | 6441760021201308946 |
+----+------+---------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: You are comparing a varchar field with '' and without them as number. So, the results are odd. But, why are you doing so though?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare column named 'simuid', which is a varchar, to a number, namely 6441760021201308940. This may lead to such unexpected behaviours. If you want to compare a number with varchar, you must first cast the simuid column value to a number, i.e. UNSIGNED 64 bit type. Example:

```
select * from user where CAST(simuid AS UNSIGNED) = 6441760021201308940;
```

Or even better, due to the limit of UNSIGNED type length:

```
select * from user where simuid = CAST(6441760021201308940 AS char);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but the results of these two statements are the same, but why ---------select * from user where simuid = 6441760021201308940---------; will return all rows

Comment: This is because you are doing thing that you should not be doing. You cant compare other datatypes without first converting them, otherwise you won't have correct behaviour. Why is it like that? Because SQL has its specification, something is happening 'under the hood' that is resulting in such set being selected.
Image that you are comparing 100€ to 100$. You can't do that without first converting € to $ or $ to €. You are doing the same here. Compare string to number, which are other datatypes.

Comment: I understand, but what causes it? Does mysql perform type conversion?

Answer (score 0):

It is because when you are doing the number comparison you are really doing

```
select * from user where stringtoint(simuid) = 6441760021201308940
```

But the number data type does not have enough precision to store a value as big as yours exactly. Therefore what really happens is more like

```
select * from user where truncate(stringtoint(simuid)) = truncate(6441760021201308940)
```

So all numbers that are approximately the same as the one you are looking for will be truncated to the same value, and therefore be considered to be equal

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but if this is the case, why does it return a row when the value is less than or equal to 6441760021201308160, and when it is greater than this value, it returns all rows greater than this value?

Comment: @mzc that's a more interesting question, but it's not the question you asked.

Comment: @Strawberry  Under normal circumstances, MySQL will help us to do type conversion, but I don't understand why this threshold will be different.

Comment: Sure. I suggest you edit your question, or ask a new one, along the lines of why does casting ...8159 = x work but ...8160 (And all values above it) doesn't

Comment: @mzc I don't think it returns all rows greater than the value. I think it returns all rows between this value and some other value. Your ID is higher than the highest integer that the data type can represent exactly, which is why there is a cutoff value where it stops working